# Rewriting URL Via .htaccess Using It's Categoryname Not It's Value

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know the basic re-writing of URL via `.htaccess`, right now I try to use other of writing URL paths because most of the web developers knows how to write `.htaccess` files. The following paths below I desired. using the name not its value. **Is this possible for `.htaccess`, or theirs an existing way to do this, or not?**

THE BASIC WAY:

```
Original URL:
      http://www.example.com/index.php?category=fish?name=milkfish

    Basic Output URL:
      http://www.example.com/category/fish/milkfish
```

**I LOOKING FOR:**

```
Original URL:
   http://www.example.com/index.php?category=fish?name=milkfish

Desired destination URL:
   http://www.example.com/category/category/name
```

Comment: You have a category and a subcategory or you want example.com/fish/fish/milkfish?

Comment: with true values im reading it as `/category/fish/milkfish`?

Comment: That was the basic output example

Comment: @TechGirl Hope my post will help you out...

Comment: Your original URLs are strictly invalid - you have two question marks (just a typo)? But the "desired destination URL" doesn't seem to make sense? `/category/category/name` - where do these path segments come from? What was wrong with (or how does it differ from)  `/category/fish/milkfish`?

Comment: Okay I try to do the following codes to make another way of re-writing URL given by Sahil Gulati then I realize that even if I use the name not its value nothing happen and what I'm looking for. I realize that if I use http://www.example.com/category/category/name then what do I need to put into my query? If I put category it ask what category do I looking for. Then I think that these things is not possible. @w3dk

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you out.. You can check this `.htaccess` code [here](http://htaccess.mwl.be)

> **1. Condition** `REQUEST_URI` should be `/index.php`
>
> **2. Condition** `QUERY_STRING` should be in this format `category=somevalue&name=somename`

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} category=([\w]+)\&name=([\w]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /category/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: But this only appears to be half a solution... what about rewriting from the "desired" URL back to the "original" URL?

Comment: Thanks for the codes you've given sir. But I think this is not possible for an htaccess to do so and even it does, querying are next question or next topic. But I still looking for a geekies answer about this. @Sahil Gulati